# No sound on HP X2 atom after LUbuntu 22.04.4 LTS fresh install

Tags: sound, lubuntu

My HP X2 previously had Win10 installed but due to 2GB of RAM and 30GB built-in disk I decided to install Lubuntu

Unfortunaltely there is no sound when I play back an audio file or watch youtube.

After some research at ask ubuntu I could find some hints but I couldn't solve the problem.

This might help:

```
uname -a
Linux X2 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 22)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 22)
00:0a.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 22d8 (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 22)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 22)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)

inxi -A
Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install inxi

cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Audio          ]: HdmiLpeAudio - Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
                      Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
 1 [cx2072x        ]: SOF - sof-bytcht cx2072x
                      HP-HPPavilionx2Detachable-Type1ProductConfigId-813E

lspci -v | grep -i audio
(no result)

cat /proc/asound/devices
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 2]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 0]   : control
  6: [ 1- 0]: digital audio playback
  7: [ 1- 0]: digital audio capture
  8: [ 1- 1]: digital audio playback
  9: [ 1]   : control
 33:        : timer

aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: cx2072x [sof-bytcht cx2072x], device 0: PCM (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: cx2072x [sof-bytcht cx2072x], device 1: PCM Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

grep snd /proc/asound/modules
 0 snd_hdmi_lpe_audio
 1 snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_cx2072x

lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_cx2072x    16384  4
snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt    20480  0
snd_sof_acpi           16384  1 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_atom     20480  1 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     12288  1 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof               356352  3 snd_sof_intel_atom,snd_sof_acpi,snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof_utils          16384  1 snd_sof
snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    94208  2 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_intel_sst_core     73728  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform   118784  1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_soc_acpi           12288  3 snd_sof_intel_atom,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_cx2072x        61440  1
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_soc_core          446464  4 snd_soc_cx2072x,snd_sof,snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_cx2072x,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               12288  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hdmi_lpe_audio     40960  2
snd_pcm               196608  9 snd_soc_cx2072x,snd_sof,snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_cx2072x,snd_compress,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           24576  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            57344  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq               118784  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              49152  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   143360  22 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

PulseAudioVolumeControl showed headphones plugged in.
Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343892)